# mbedtls mutual authentication

Tags: tls, rsa, pkcs1

I have a server CA cert, device cert and the device private key.  I am using `mbedtls` and want to be able to create a mutual authentication connection between the device and the server.  I also have to RSA PKCS and am getting an error whilst parsing the private key - `mbedtls_pk_parse_keyfile returned -0x3e80`.

Can some kind soul point to an example using `mbedtls` or help me understand the problem?

Comment: do you mean this? https://tls.mbed.org/ If so, this is a programming question, not a security question. And they have a support page: https://tls.mbed.org/kb

Comment: I would migrate to Stack Overflow, but you do not provide any code or explain what you did, so they would reject it.

Comment: off topic? lol - usual rubbish from these sites....

Comment: You have asked the wrong people the wrong question. I'm sorry that you feel that it response is rubbish. You also do not provide enough info for the right people to help. I'd love to help but you aren't meeting us half way.